# @Resource is creating controller that shadows my own controller

Tags: grails, hateoas, grails-2.4

To render JSON+HAL I've added `@Resource` anotation to my domain:

```
@Resource(uri = "/rest/book", formats=['hal'])
class Book {
    String title
    String author
}
```

The problem is that I already have `BookController` (no scaffolding) and creating ling via gsp tag (`<g:createLink controller='book' />`) always creates link to `/rest/book` not to specyfic action in controller (i.e. `/book/index`). What is also worth knowing when I type `localhost:8080/book/index` it is showing JSON response not gsp page.

The `@Resource` somehow cover the book controller and  I don't know how to keep both of them working.

PS I'm using **Grails 2.4.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [namespaces](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#namespacedControllers) for your controller.

```
class BookController {

    static namespace = 'namespaceOne'

    // …
}
```

and then use the namespace to generate links to your BookController.

```
<g:link controller="book" namespace="namespaceOne">Click me</g:link>
```